# Merger of "corrupt/incomplete" and "deleted" images on CF cards questions?

Tags: discussion, mergers

I'm not really sure if we should merge the following two questions about CF cards, or leave them as separate questions. Deletion is one thing, where as corruption is something different, and may require more work to recover. While the tools to perform these two tasks may be the same, when it comes to searching for the answer, I am wondering if it would be best to keep the two topics (and primarily the titles and tags) distinct. This might support people searching for such answers with internet search engines easier, since we do produce a lot of google fodder.

- [Is there a way to read or recover corrupted/incomplete photos on CF card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23065/corrupted-incomplete-photos-on-cf-card)
- [How can I recover deleted photos from an SD Card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-recover-deleted-photos-from-an-sd-card)

Comment: What about SD vs CF? (I think for all practical purposes the answer will be the same, but we'll want both for search findability.)

Comment: Well, I think we could do with just two questions, and fold in SD into the titles and maybe bodies.

Comment: @mattdm It was my understanding that when questions are merged, the original "hangs around", which might cover search issues?